# Google Sheets How do I use take a cell value, search it in another tab, and when a match is found, grab all rows?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Good evening everyone! I would love if someone could help me with an issue im having. Currently, I have a google spreadsheet. 3 tabs. 2 have data. 1 is empty. I'm trying to combine the 2 tabs with data into the 3rd.

Here is an example of the 2 tabs with data.

Sheet 1

```
A column   B column  C column  D column
1234       Loc1      sec2      port 32
1344       Loc2      sec3      port 44
1555       Loc3      sec4      Port 31
```

Sheet 2

```
A column   B column  C column  D column
1344       Hardware  fiber      Down
1555       Network   optic      Up
1234       hardware  fiber      Down
```

Sheet 3 is empty. I need to combine the first 2 tabs together correctly into the third.
As you can see, sheet 1 and Sheet 2 have the same values in the "A Column" however, they are mixed up. I need all the data from both sheets, but arranged and matched according to the A column.

How would Import all data from Sheet 1 into Sheet 3, then take the A column, and search Sheet 2 for a match, once found, then pull each cell in the row and move into Sheet 3 next to the other data from sheet 1?

Desired format in sheet 3

Sheet 3

```
A column   B column  C column  D column  E Column  F column  G column
1234       Loc1      sec2      port 32   Hardware  fiber     Down
1344       Loc2      sec3      port 44    Hardware fiber     Down
1555       Loc3      sec4      Port 31    Network  optic     Up
```

I greatly appreciate anyones time that helps with this issue!! Have a great night!

Comment: sounds like vlookup for gsheets. maybe this will help: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/05/vlookup-google-sheets-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below formula in sheet3:

```
=Iferror(ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet1!A2:D,vlookup(Sheet1!A2:A,Sheet2!A2:D,{2,3,4},0)}),"")
```

Comment: That worked great!! Thank you so much!! If you have time, would you mind explaining the formula to me? I appreciate it!!!